# Yii2 arrayHelper::toArray не выводить если значение свойства NULL

Tags: php, yii2, yii, rest

Использую хелпер **Yii2** **arrayHelper::toArray()** и не вижу способа как не выводить значение в массив если значение равно NULL.

Конечно можно всё перегнать через цикл без хелпера, но у меня есть колбеки.

**Пример кода:**

```
return ArrayHelper::toArray( $Model, [
    UserProfile::class => [
       'id',
       'name',
       'message',
       'type_id',
       'map_lat' => function( $model ) { return $model->map_lat ? doubleval( $model->map_lat ) : ''; },
       'map_long' => function( $model ) { return $model->map_lat ? doubleval( $model->map_long ) : ''; },
       'targets' => function( UserProfile $model ) {
           return $model->getUserProfileRelationshipTypes()
              ->select('profile_relationship_type_id')
              ->column();
       },
       'city_id'
   ]
]);
```

Повторю вопрос по примеру из кода.

Как не возвращать данные из свойства **map_lat**, если **map_lat** равно **NULL** ? То есть в выводе массив не должен содержать поля массива **map_lat** если у них значение **NULL**.

Comment: Добрый день.
Попробуйте обработать массив через [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: Хотелось бы как то описать это в модели, что если свойство **NULL** то не выводить его.
Спасибо, но фильтровать не хочется. Что то придумаю с Yii2

Comment: В любом случае Вы будете получать пустые значения модели. Откуда Вы сможете определить, какое поле пустое, а какое нет? Вы получаете запись по id. И для разных экземпляров моделей будет разный набор полей, заполненных и нет. Поэтому решение с array_filter() вполне приемлемо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
return array_diff(ArrayHelper::toArray($Model, [
    UserProfile::class => [
       'id',
       'name',
       'message',
       'type_id',
       'map_lat' => function( $model ) { return $model->map_lat ? doubleval( $model->map_lat ) : ''; },
       'map_long' => function( $model ) { return $model->map_lat ? doubleval( $model->map_long ) : ''; },
       'targets' => function( UserProfile $model ) {
           return $model->getUserProfileRelationshipTypes()
              ->select('profile_relationship_type_id')
              ->column();
       },
       'city_id'
   ]
]), ['', null]);
```

Comment: Спасибо, подумаю над вашим предложением.